# Choose largest odd number python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a simple program in Python that calculates the largest odd number out of the values x, y, z.  How do I give the user an option to pick the values for x, y, and z?

So the program will ask what x, y, and z is and then say "x,y,z is the largest odd" or the numbers are all even.

What I have so far is below.  Is this at least a decent start?

```
  # This program exmamines variables x, y, and z 
  # and prints the largest odd number among them

  if x%2 !== 0 and x > y and y > z:
      print 'x is the largest odd among x, y, and z'
  elif y%2 !== 0 and y > z and z > x:
     print 'y is the largest odd among x, y, and z'
  elif z%2 !== 0 and z > y and y > x:
     print 'z is the largest odd among x, y, and z'
  elif x%2 == 0 or y%2 == 0 or z%2 == 0:
     print 'even'
```

With thkang post, I now have:

```
  # This program exmamines variables x, y, and z 
  # and prints the largest odd number among them

  if x%2 !== 0:
    if y%2 !== 0:
      if z%2 !== 0:
        if x > y and x > z: #x is the biggest odd
        elif y > z and y > x: #y is the biggest odd
        elif z > x and z > y: #z is the biggest odd

      else: #z is even
        if x > y: #x is the biggest odd
        else: #y is the biggest odd

    else: #y is even
      if z%2 != 0: #z is odd
        if x > z: #x is the biggest odd
        else: #z is the biggest odd
      else: #y,z are even and x is the biggest odd

  else: #x is even
    if y%2 != 0 and z%2 != 0; #y,z is odd
      if y > z: #y is the biggest odd
      else: #z is the biggest odd
    else: #x and y is even
      if z%2 != 0: #z is the biggest odd
```

Comment: Basically if you have an input like: 3, 7, 2. Your application will print 7. So the first thing to do is probably sort them and then check from the biggest to see if it is an odd, if any of them is odd, print it. If none of them is, print another message.

Comment: This isn't a homework or take home interview question is it? :P

Comment: @BjornTipling this is a question out of Intro to Comp and Programming Using Python.

Comment: Side note: python allows you to write `x > y > z` for `x > y and y > z`, an behaves as inteded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it would be better to filter the numbers, then sort them.

```
numbers = [x, y, z]

sorted_odd_nums = sorted((x for x in enumerate(numbers) if x[1]%2), 
                         key = lambda x:x[1], 
                         reverse=True)

if not sorted_odd_nums:
   # all numbers were even and filtered out.
elif sorted_odd_nums[0][0] == 0:
   # x is the biggest odd number
elif sorted_odd_nums[0][0] == 1:
   # y is the biggest odd number
elif sorted_odd_nums[0][0] == 2:
   # z is the biggest odd number
```

## what it does:

`enumerate(numbers)` returns a sequence of `(index, item)` pairs. since original list was `[x, y, z]`, we can keep the track of `x`, `y`, `z` even after filter and sort.

`(x for x in enumerate(numbers) if x[1]%2)` filters above enumeration if the second item in given tuple is not an even number.

`sort( ... , key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)` sorts filtered items using value of their second-indexed item(which is original number) in descending order.

## user input

to read from user, the easiest way is using `raw_input`(py2) / `input`(py3k).

```
number = int(raw_input('enter a number: '))
```

## using only if-statements

you'd have to nest if-statements. like:

```
if x%2: # x is odd
  if y%2: # y is odd
    if z%2: #z is odd
      if x>y and x>z: #x is the biggest odd number
      elif y>z and y>x: #y is the biggest odd number
      elif z>x and z>y: #z is the biggest odd number

    else: #z is even
      if x>y: #x is the biggest odd number
      else: #y is the biggest odd number
  else: #y is even
    if z%2: #z is odd
...
```

Comment: Or sort them and then just get the first largest odd number, that way you go through the list less often. Or you could prioritize oddness over value in a custom sort function.

Comment: @thkang I am only in the if then else section of the book.  This way may be more efficient but can we do it without I know?

Comment: @dustin for x, y, z there are 8 cases of their parity (from `x=odd, y=odd, z=odd` to `x=even, y=even, z=even`) and 6 cases of putting them in a line(from `x, y, z` to `z, y, x`) which gives you 48 cases. It'd be a long if-elif-else statement!

Comment: @thkang that may be so but I am only just learning Python on my own so I need to take baby steps.  It won't do me any good to not fully understand the code.

Comment: @dustin: You aren't going to get any better at Python by writing out long `if-else` statements. Once you understand the concept, go on to the next thing, and just keep in mind there are better ways to solve this problem.

Comment: @thkang should that be mod 3 instead of 2 for odd?

Comment: @dustin condition `x%2` is true if `x%2` is not 0, which means x is an odd number.

Comment: @thkang so one cold put either x%2 or x%2 !== 0 to achieve the same result of odd?  I have edited my OP to add your suggestion and finish the sequence of nested if then else.  Is it correct now?

Comment: @dustin your code lacks edge cases where only one number in x, y, z is odd, and the boolean not-equal operator is `!=`, not `!==`

Comment: @dustin looks so, but you should test it yourself. :D

Comment: @thkang When I try to run the code, it tells me x isn't defined.

Answer (score 11):

## Approach

Avoid using `if-stmts` to find maximum. Use python builtin `max`. Use either generator or `filter` to find only the odd numbers.

Using builtins like this is safer/more reliable because it is simpler to compose them, the code is well-tested, and the code executes mostly in C (rather than multiple byte code instructions).

## Code

```
def find_largest_odd(*args):
    return max(arg for arg in args if arg & 1)
```

or:

```
def find_largest_odd(*args):
    return max(filter(lambda x: x & 1, args))
```

## Test

```
>>> def find_largest_odd(*args):
...     return max(arg for arg in args if arg & 1)
... 
>>> print find_largest_odd(1, 3, 5, 7)
7
>>> print find_largest_odd(1, 2, 4, 6)
1
```

and:

```
>>> def find_largest_odd(*args):
...     return max(filter(lambda x: x & 1, args))
>>> print find_largest_odd(1, 3, 5, 7)
7
>>> print find_largest_odd(1, 2, 4, 6)
1
```

If you pass an empty sequence or provide only even numbers, you will get a `ValueError`:

```
>>> find_largest_odd(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in find_largest_odd
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

## References

- [filter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter)
- [max](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max)
- [generators](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generators)

Answer (score 6):

Incase anyone is looking for a simple solution using condition statements

```
x,y,z = 4,1,6
largest = None
if x%2:
 largest = x
if y%2:
 if y > largest:
  largest = y
if z%2:
 if z > largest:
  largest = z
if largest:
 print "largest number is" largest
else
 print "there are no odd numbers"
```

Comment: If x is even number it skips assigning x to largest and it raises a type error. Assign 0 to largest variable and not None.

Answer (score 4):

```
try:
    largest = max(val for val in (x,y,z) if val % 2)
    print(largest)
except ValueError:
    print('Even')
```

Note that `sorted` is a `O(n log n)` operation, while `max` is `O(n)`. The speed difference may not matter for sequences that are this short, but it is good practice to use the best tool for the job.

Answer (score 4):

This is the finger exercise from Ch.2 of Introduction to Computation and Programming Using Python by John V. Guttag. It's the recommended text for the MITx: 6.00x Introduction to Computer Science and Programming. The book is written to be used with Python 2.7.

'Write a program that examines three variables x,y and z, and prints the largest odd number among them. If none of them are odd, it should print a message to that effect.'

At this point the book has only introduced variable assignment and conditional branching programs and the print function. I know as I'm working through it. To that end this is the code I wrote:

```
if x%2 == 0:
    if y%2 == 0:
        if z%2 == 0:
            print "None of them are odd"
        else:
            print z
    elif y > z or z%2 == 0:
        print y
    else:
        print z
elif y%2 == 0:
    if z%2 == 0 or x > z:
        print x
    else:
        print z
elif z%2 == 0:
    if x > y:
        print x
    else:
        print y
else:
    if x > y and x > z:
        print x
    elif y > z:
        print y
    else:
        print z
```

It seems to work for all the combinations I have tried, but it would be useful to know if it can be shortened bearing in mind my points from paragraph three. I appreciate it has been aswered, but by providing this answer, other users are more likely to come across it when searching for answers to the question in the book.

Answer (score 3):

something like this:

```
def get_max_odd(*lis):
    try:
         return sorted(i for i in lis if i%2)[-1] #IndexError if no odd item found
    except IndexError:    
         return "even"


In [8]: get_max_odd(1,2,3)
Out[8]: 3

In [9]: get_max_odd(2,4,6)
Out[9]: 'even'

In [10]: get_max_odd(2,5,6)
Out[10]: 5

In [11]: get_max_odd(2,4,6,8,9,10,20)
Out[11]: 9
```

Answer (score 2):

I am working my way through the same book by Guttag (and Python 2.7). Others reading it may take cognisance that lists (or slicing them) haven't been introduced yet though I have used one in my solution (I think it works fine!?!). And you don't really need to reverse the list order if you would rather slice from the end instead of the beginning of the list.

First I created an empty list (lst). But before I use it I check if all of x, y and z are not odd (Guttag asks if 'none of them are odd'). Then, each variable in turn is checked to see if its odd and if it is, it gets added to the list. I sorted the list in a descending order (i.e. largest odd numbers to the front).. then check to make sure that it has at least one element (no point in printing an empty list) and then print the first element.

```
x,y,z = 111,45,67

lst = []
if x%2==0 and y%2==0 and z%2==0:
    print 'none of x,y or z is an odd number'
else:
    if x%2!=0:
        lst.append(x)
    if y%2!=0:
        lst.append(y)
    if z%2!=0:
        lst.append(z)
lst.sort(reverse = True)
if len(lst)!=0:
    print lst[:1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution:

```
def get_max_odd(x, y, z):
    odd_nums = []

    if x % 2 == 1:
        odd_nums.append(x)
    if y % 2 == 1:
        odd_nums.append(y)
    if z % 2 == 1:
        odd_nums.append(z)

    if odd_nums == []:
        return 'None of x, y, z are odd numbers'
    else:
        return max(odd_nums)

print(get_max_odd(120, 111, 23))
```

I was not able to complete this excercise using ONLY the material presented
thus far in the book. In fact, I don't think it's possible to having a
working program without it being over 100 lines. Please let me know if you
have found a way to make it work with ONLY the material presented thus far

Comment: Something like:
`def largest_odd(x, y, z):\n
 m = None\n
 if x % 2 == 1 and (m is None or x > m):\n
  m = x\n
 if y % 2 == 1 and (m is None or y > m):\n
  m = y\n
 if z % 2 == 1 and (m is None or z > m):\n
  m = z\n
 if m is None:\n
  print('None of them are odd')\n
 else:\n
  print(m)\n` (replace \n with line endings; I can't get the formatting right in a comment)

Answer (score 2):

In the first 4 line of code we are asking the user to enter a number and converting that number to an integer

```
x = input("enter a number:")

y = input("enter another number: ")

z = input("enter another number: ")

x,y,z = int(x),int(y),int(z)


if x %2 !=0: # check whether x is odd

    if y%2 !=0: # if x is odd check y

        if z%2 != 0: # if y is odd then check z
            if x>z and x > y: # comparing the 3 numbers as all are odd to get largest
                print("x is largest")
            elif y>z:
                print("y is largest")
            else:
                print("z is largest")
        else: # if z is not an odd number then the above comparisons cannot be done #
    #so we placed this else if z is not odd then the below comparisons will be executed
            if x>z and x > y:
                print("x is largest")
            elif y>z:
                print("y is largest")
    else: # if y is also not an even and x is odd then x is largest irrespective of others
        print("x is largest")

elif y%2 != 0: # similar way if x is not odd then the above loop will not run so this gets executed when x is even

    if z%2 != 0:
        if y>z:
            print("y is largest")
    else:
        print("z is largest")
elif z%2 !=0:

    print("z is largest")
else:

    print("all the numbers are even")
```

Comment: The code might answer the question but this way the OP does not learn why the code answers it. So pls explain your code to the OP.

Comment: Thanks Markus this is the first question where I am posting an answer so thanks for the suggestion it will help

Answer (score 2):

```
def odd(x,y,z):
    l=[x,y,z]
    even=[]
    for e in l:
        if e%2!=0:
            even.append(e)
    even.sort()
    if len(even)==0:
        return(print('No odd numbers'))
    else:
        return(even[-1])

odd(1,2,3)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, please highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar or using Ctrl+K on your keyboard to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code could solve the problem, it is best to add elaboration and explain how it works for people who might not understand this piece of code.

Answer (score 2):

As per in the comments, the post by AfDev and others will throw a TypeError if x is even, as it will attempt

```
if y > None:
```

Edit: The commentor's solution (initialising largest = 0 instead of largest = None) will not work either if the highest odd is negative.

The question from the book assumes no knowledge of lists or loops so here's my solution:

```
x, y, z = 2, -5, -9
largest = None

if x % 2 != 0:
    largest = x
if y % 2 != 0:
    if largest == None or y > largest: # if None it will not attempt 2nd conditional
        largest = y
if z % 2 != 0:
    if largest == None or z > largest:
        largest = z

print(largest) # prints -5
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the first script I have written in my career after contemplating on it since yesterday evening.

Actually I was looking for answer to refer as I was constantly getting errors but could not find anything satisfactory, here is one from me :)

```
x = 333312
y = 221569
z = 163678

if x%2 ==0 and y%2==0 and z%2==0:
    print "Only even numbers provided."

elif x%2==0:
    if y%2!=0 and z%2!=0:
        if y > z:
            print y
        else:
            print z
    else:
        if y%2!=0:
            print y
        if z%2!=0:
            print z


elif y%2==0:
    if x%2!=0 and z%2!=0:
        if x > z:
            print x
        else:
            print z
    else:
        if x%2!=0:
            print x
        if z%2!=0:
            print z



elif z%2==0:
    if x%2!=0 and y%2!=0:
                if x > y:
                    print x
                else:
                    print y
    else:
        if x%2!=0:
                print x
        if y%2!=0:
                print y

else:
    if x>y and x>z:
        print x
    elif y>z:
        print y   
    else:
        print z
```

Answer (score 1):

I am also currently going through the book and came across this problem. I used an approach similar to some of the solutions above. However, instead of just printing the largest value, the program prints the variable holding the largest value as well.

The difference here becomes that rather than checking if `x > y`, `x > z`, etc., the program also checks for equality (i.e. `x >= y`, `x >= z`, etc.). For multiple equal values, the program will print all the variables that share the highest odd value.

> Finger Exercise 2.2
>
> Write a program that examines three variables- x, y, and z- and prints the
>   largest odd number among them.
>   If none of them are odd, it should print a message to that effect.

```
x, y, z = 5,7,7

if x%2 == 1 or y%2 == 1 or z%2 == 1: #at least one of the variables is odd
    if x%2 == 1:
        if y%2 == 1:
            if z%2 == 1: #x, y, and z are all odd
                if x >= y and x >= z:
                    print "x =", x, "is the largest odd number!"
                if y >= x and y >=z:
                    print "y =",y, "is the largest odd number!"
                if z >= x and z >= y:
                    print "z =", z, "is the largest odd number!"
            else: #z is even, but x and y are still odd
                if x >= y:
                    print "x =", x, "is the largest odd number!"
                if y >= x:
                    print "y =",y, "is the largest odd number!"
        elif z%2 == 1: #y is even, but x and z are odd
            if x >= z:
                print "x =", x, "is the largest odd number!"
            if z >= x:
                print "z =", z, "is the largest odd number!"
        else: #x is the only odd number
            print "x = ", x, "is the largest odd number!"
    if x%2 != 1 and y %2 == 1: #x is not odd but y is odd
    #could have done an elif here. But this makes the code easier to follow
        if z%2 == 1:#z is also odd
            if y >=z:
                print "y =",y, "is the largest odd number!"
            if z >= y:
                print "z =", z, "is the largest odd number!"
        else: #z is even. Hence, y is the only odd number
            print "y =", y, "is the largest odd number!"
    if x%2 != 1 and y%2 != 1 and z%2 == 1:#z is the only odd number
        print "z =", z, "is the largest odd number!"             
else:
    print "No odd number was input!"
```

Answer (score 1):

This answers the last finger exercise in the Ch.02 of the book by Prof. John Guttag mentioned in earlier posts. Using lists seemed helpful to me. The same method can be used for the previous finger exercise in the same chapter.

```
import math



a=int(input("Enter first integer: ")) # Manual entering of ten integers#
b=int(input("Enter second integer: "))
c=int(input("Enter third integer: "))
d=int(input("Enter fourth integer: "))
e=int(input("Enter fifth integer: "))
f=int(input("Enter sixth integer: "))
g=int(input("Enter seventh integer: "))
h=int(input("Enter eighth integer: "))
i=int(input("Enter ninth integer: "))
j=int(input("Enter tenth integer: "))

master=[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j]



def ifalleven(a): # Finding whether every integer in the list if even or not.#

    i=0
    list=[]
    while i<len(a):
        if a[i]%2==0:
            list.append(a[i])
        i=i+1
    return len(list)==len(a)



def findodd(a): # Finding the greatest odd integer on the list.#
    i=0
    list=[]
    while i<len(a):
        if a[i]%2!=0:
            list.append(a[i])
        i=i+1
    print (max(list))



def greatoddoreven(list): # Finding the greatest odd integer on the list or if none are odd, print a message to that effect.#
    if ifalleven(list)==True:
        print ('No odd numbers found!')
    else:
        findodd(list)



greatoddoreven(master)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am learning Python and programming as well. My answer for this exercise as follow. Working through finger exercise from Ch.2 of Introduction to Computation and Programming Using Python by John V. Guttag.

```
x, y, z = 55, 90, 87

if x%2 == 1 and y%2 == 1 and z%2 == 1:
   if x > y and x > z:
        print (x)
   elif y > z and y >x:
        print (y)
   else:
        print (z)
else:   
    print ('none of them are odd')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
num1 = 7
num2 = 16
num3 = 300
x1=0
x2=0
x3=0

if num1%2 != 0:
    x1=1
if num2%2 != 0:
    x2=1
if num3%2 != 0:
    x3=1

if (num1*x1 > num2*x2) and (num1*x1 > num3*x3):
   largest = num1
elif (num2*x2 > num1*x1) and (num2*x2 > num3*x3):
   largest = num2
elif (x3):
   largest = num3
else:
    print("no one is odd")
if(x1!=0 or x2!=0 or x3!=0):
    print("The largest odd number between",num1,",",num2,"and",num3,"is",largest)
```

Comment: This code expects the numbers to be positive which might not be the case.

Answer (score 1):

How's this for an answer? Is it too long?

```
 x, y, z = eval(input('Please enter the numbers for x, y, z: '))#allows you to enter three numbers each separated by a comma
print('x =', x)#Shows you what the value of x is
print('y =', y)#Shows you what the value of y is
print('z =', z)#Shows you what the value of z is
if x%2 != 0:#Checks to see if x is odd is true 
    if y%2 != 0:#Checks to see if y is odd is true
        if z%2 != 0:#Checks to see if z is odd is true
            if x > y and x > z:# Now in this situation since all the numbers are odd, all we have to do is compare them to see which is the largest in the following lines
                print('x is the largest odd number')
            elif y > z:    
                print('y is the largest odd number')
            else:    
                print('z is the largest odd number')
        elif x > y:# we refer back to the line if z%2 != 0 and in this new situation, it is false therefore z is not odd in this case and x and y are the only odd numbers here
                print('x is the largest odd number')  # we check to see if x is the largest odd number, if x is not largest odd number then proceed to the next line      
        else: 
                print('y is the largest odd number')  # here, y is the largest odd number                                                  
    elif z%2 != 0:# refer back to the sixth line at the beginning, if y%2 = 0.In this new situation, y is not odd so the only variables we're comparing now are x and z only
        if x > z:
            print('x is the largest odd number')
        else:
            print('z is the largest odd number')
    else:
            print('x is the largest odd number')# when both y and z are not odd, by default x is the largest odd number here
elif y%2 != 0:# Refer back to the fifth line, if x%2 != 0, in this new situation, the statement if x%2 != 0 is false therefore we proceed to checking if the next variable y is odd right here
            if z%2 != 0:#Since y is odd, check to see if z is odd,
                if y > z:#then if previous statement is true check to see now if y is bigger and print('y is the largest odd number') if so
                    print('y is the largest odd number')
                else:
                    print('z is the largest odd number')# here y is not largest odd number so by default z is the largest

            else:# this line occurs when z is not odd which pretty much leaves y to be the only odd number and is therefore largest odd number by default
                print('y is the largest odd number')
elif z%2 != 0:# this line occurs when both x and y is not odd which leaves z to be the largest odd number
            print('z is the largest odd number')
else:# this line occurs when all the numbers are not odd; they are even. Remember in this program, our main objective is to determine the largest number only among the odd numbers if there are any odd numbers at all, and if there are no odd numbers we show that there are none. (We do not take into account even numbers at all since that's not what the question is about) 
    print('There are no odd numbers')
```

Comment: You could possibly add some explanation to the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
x=input('x= ')
y=input('y= ')
z=input('z= ')
largest = None
if x%2 == 0 and y%2 == 0 and z%2 == 0:
    print('none of them is odd')
else:
    if x%2 != 0:
        largest = x
    if y%2 != 0:
        if y > largest:
            largest = y
    if z%2 != 0:
        if z > largest:
            largest = z
    print(largest)
```

Answer (score 1):

just finished working the same problem. My answer seems different from the other ones but seems to be working fine.( Or am I missing something?!) so here is an alternative:

With only if/else:

```
    x = 4
    y = 7
    z = 7

    if x%2 and y%2 and z%2 == 1:
        if x > y and x > z:
            print x
        elif y > z:
            print y
        else:
            print z
    elif x%2 and y%2 == 1:
        if x > y:
            print x
        else:
            print y
    elif x%2 and z%2 == 1 :
        if x > z:
            print x
        else:
            print z
    elif y%2 and z%2 == 1:
        if y > z:
            print y
        else:
            print z
    elif x%2 == 1:
        print x
    elif y%2 == 1:
        print y
    elif z%2 == 1:
        print z
    else:
        print "there are no odd numbers"
```

as far as I know it works with negative, numbers, big numbers, ... if not let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my "rookie" version of the solution. Basically the problem requires the analysis of all possible combinations of X, Y, Z depending on user input (eg., cases such as one odd and two even numbers, etc.).

I first eliminated the two most obvious cases when all numbers are even and at least one of the numbers is zero. The code is missing only the part when *at least two numbers* are equal. The rest is straightforward...

There is definitely a much refined approach to the problem (see below for cases with more combinations of ingredient variables using sorting and reverse comparison) but this is what I could accomplish with my basic knowledge of Python.

```
print('This program will find the largest odd number among the three entered.\nSo, let\'s start...\n')

x = int(input('Enter the 1st number: '))
y = int(input('Enter the 2nd number: '))
z = int(input('Enter the 3rd number: '))
strToPrint = ' is the largest odd number.'

if x==0 or y==0 or z==0:
    print('\nNo zeroes, please. Re-run the program.')
    exit()
if x % 2 == 0 and y % 2 == 0 and z % 2 == 0:
    print('\nAll numbers are even.')
elif x % 2 != 0 and y % 2 != 0 and z % 2 != 0:  # all numbers are odd; start analysis...
    if x > y and x > z:
        print(str(x) + strToPrint)
    if y > x and y > z:
        print(str(y) + strToPrint)
    if z > y and z > x:
        print(str(z) + strToPrint)
elif x % 2 != 0 and y % 2 == 0 and z % 2 == 0:  # only X is odd.
    print(str(x) + strToPrint)
elif y % 2 != 0 and x % 2 == 0 and z % 2 == 0:  # only Y is odd.
    print(str(y) + strToPrint)
elif z % 2 != 0 and x % 2 == 0 and y % 2 == 0:  # only Z is odd.
    print(str(z) + strToPrint)
elif x % 2 != 0 and y % 2 != 0 and z % 2 == 0:  # only X and Y are odd.
    if x > y:
        print(str(x) + strToPrint)
    else:
        print(str(y) + strToPrint)
elif x % 2 != 0 and y % 2 == 0 and z % 2 != 0:  # only X and Z are odd.
    if x > z:
        print(str(x) + strToPrint)
    else:
        print(str(z) + strToPrint)
elif x % 2 == 0 and y % 2 != 0 and z % 2 != 0:  # only Z and Y are odd.
    if y > z:
        print(str(y) + strToPrint)
    else:
        print(str(z) + strToPrint)
```

Below is the "non-rookie" version of the same program for any (reasonable) number of integers, which is shorter and more compact compared to the previous version. I used a list of ten integers for demonstration only, but the list can be extended.

```
int_list = [100, 2, 64, 98, 89, 25, 70, 76, 23, 5]
i = len(int_list) - 1           # we'll start from the end of a sorted (!) list
int_list.sort()                 # sort the list first

# print(int_list)               # just to check that the list is indeed sorted. You can uncomment to print the sorted list, too.

while i >= 0:                   # prevent 'out of range' error
    if int_list[i] % 2 != 0:    # check if the list item is an odd number
        break                   # since the list is sorted, break at the first occurence of an odd number
    i -= 1                      # continue reading list items if odd number isn't found

print('The largest odd number is: ' + str(int_list[i]) + ' (item #' + str(i) + ' in the sorted list)')
```

Comment: Please include your solution in the answer instead of posting a link to it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my interpretation, I am doing the same task which is part of the Book *Introduction to Computation and Programming Using Python, 2nd ed, John Guttag*

```
# edge cases 100, 2, 3 and 100,2,-3 and 2,2,2
x = 301
y = 2
z = 1

# what if the largest number is not odd? We need to discard any non-odd numbers

# if none of them are odd - go straight to else
if (x % 2 != 0) or (y % 2 != 0) or (z % 2 != 0):
    #codeblock if we have some odd numbers
    print("ok")
    
    # initialising the variable with one odd number, so we check each in turn
    if (x % 2 != 0):
        largest = x
    elif (y % 2 != 0):
        largest = y
    elif (z % 2 != 0):
        largest = z

    # here we check each against the largest
    # no need to check for x as we did already

    if (y % 2 != 0):
        if y > largest:
            largest = y
    
    if (z % 2 != 0):
        if z > largest:
            largest = z
    
    print("The largest odd number is:", largest)
    print("The numbers were", x, y, z)
        
else: 
    print("No odd number found")`
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code for Guttag's Finger exercise 2:

```
def is_odd(x):
    """returns True if x is odd else returns False"""
    if x % 2 != 0:
        return(True)
    else:
        return(False)

def is_even(x):
    """returns True if x is even else returns False"""
    if x % 2 == 0:
        return(True)
    else:
        return(False)

def largest_odd(x, y, z):
    """Returns the largest odd among the three given numbers"""
    if is_odd(x) and is_odd(y) and is_odd(z):
        return(max(x, y, z))
    elif is_odd(x) and is_odd(y) and is_even(z):
        return(max(x, y))
    elif is_odd(x) and is_even(y) and is_odd(z):
        return(max(x, z))
    elif is_even(x) and is_odd(y) and is_odd(z):
        return(max(y, z))
    elif is_odd(x) and is_even(y) and is_even(z):
        return(x)
    elif is_even(x) and is_odd(y) and is_even(z):
        return(y)
    elif is_even(x) and is_even(y) and is_odd(z):
        return(z)
    else:
        return("There is no odd number in the input")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we aren't going to use something fancy :-) like the max and sort functions in python...I think it's safe to say than an "assignment" statement is fair game....we do after all have to assign x,y and z.

As such: I created my own variable called "largest" initialized as zero. 
I assign that variable the first odd number of x,y,z (interrogated  in that order).
Then I simply check the remaining values and if each one is greater than "largest"  and is also an odd number then I make it the value of "largest" -- and check the next value.
Once all the values are checked, "largest" holds the value of the largest odd number or zero (which means I never did find an odd number and I print a message to that effect.

This is the same method you could use to read an arbitrary number (perhaps 10) of values from a user and print the largest odd one after all values are entered. Just check each value as it's entered against the current "largest" one.

Yes, you do need to be careful to support negative odd numbers -- you need to handle the assignment of "largest" to the first odd number whether or not it's greater than zero.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually easier for me to to think about this problem with more values rather than only 3 (x,y,z). Suppose I show you a list of words  Apple, dog, Banana, cat, monkey, Zebra, elephant... etc.  Let's say there are 26 words denoted by variables a,b,c,d,e,f...x,y, and z.

If you need to find the "largest word" (in dictionary order) that begins with a lowercase letter, you don't need to compare every word with every other word. Our brains don't typically sort the entire list into order and then pick from the end either...well...mine doesn't anyway.

I just start at the front of the list and work my way through it. The first time I find a word that starts with a lowercase letter...I memorize it and then read until I get another lowercase word -- then I check which is larger and memorize just that word.... I never have to go back and check any of the others.  One pass on the list and I'm done.  In the list above...my brain immediately discards "Zebra" because the case is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The question asks to print out the largest odd number from 3 variables -x, y, and z, and since it's chapter 2 which only goes as far as describing conditionals I'm guessing the ans should be provided by using only conditionals.

The program can be completed by exhaustively writing all the possible combinations of odd or even. Since there is 3 variables and at any one time these variables can be either odd or even there is 2^3 = 8 combinations/ conditionals.
This can be shown by using a Truth Table but instead of using True and False we use 'O' for odd and 'E' for even.
The table will look like this [Odd-Even Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDk6X.png)

Each row is a conditional in the code which checks 'oddness/evenness'. Inside each of these conditionals you will then check which variables is the largest odd number using nested conditionals for this.

```
x = int(input('Enter an integer: '))
y = int(input('Enter another integer: '))
z = int(input('Enter a final integer: '))

print('x is:', x)
print('y is:', y)
print('z is:', z)
print('\n')

if x % 2 == 1 and y % 2 == 1 and z % 2 == 1:
    print('First conditional triggered.')
    if x > y and x > z:
        print(x, 'is the largest odd number.')
    elif y > x and y > z:
        print(y, 'is the largest odd number.')
    elif z > x and z > y:
        print(z, 'is the largest odd number.')
    else:
        print(x, 'is the largest odd number.')
    # This else clause covers the case in which all variables are equal.
    # As such, it doesn't matter which variable you use to output the 
    # largest as all are the largest.
elif x % 2 == 1 and y % 2 == 1 and z % 2 == 0:
    print('Second conditional is triggered.')
    if x > y:
        print(x, 'is the largest odd number.')
    elif y > x:
        print(y, 'is the largest odd number.')
    else:
        print(x, 'is the largest odd number.')
elif x % 2 == 1 and y % 2 == 0 and z % 2 == 1:
    print('Third conditional is triggered.')
    if x > z:
        print(x, 'is the largest odd number.')
    elif z > x:
        print(z, 'is the largest odd number.')
    else:
        print(x, 'is the largest odd number.')
elif x % 2 == 1 and y % 2 == 0 and z % 2 == 0:
    print('Fourth conditional is triggered.')
    print(x, 'is the largest odd number.')
elif x % 2 == 0 and y % 2 == 1 and z % 2 == 1:
    print('Fifth conditional is triggered.')
    if y > z:
        print(y, 'is the largest odd number.')
    elif z > y:
        print(z, 'is the largest odd number.')
    else:
        print(y, 'is the largest odd number.')
elif x % 2 == 0 and y % 2 == 1 and z % 2 == 0:
    print('Sixth conditional is triggered.')
    print(y, 'is the largest odd number.')
elif x % 2 == 0 and y % 2 == 0 and z % 2 == 1:
    print('Seventh conditional is triggered.')
    print(z, 'is the largest odd number.')
else:
    print('Eight conditional is triggered.')
    print('There is no largest odd number as all numbers are even.')
```

This method works fine for 3 variables but the complexity and amount of conditionals needed can rise sharply with more variables being added.

Answer (score 0):

Just done this excercise and this seems like an efficient way of doing it although it doesn't seem to handle negative numbers (I don't think it's supposed to at this level though):

```
x, y, z = 7, 6, 12
xo = 0
yo = 0
zo = 0

if x%2 == 0 and y%2 == 0 and z%2 == 0:
    print("None of the numbers are odd.")

if x%2 == 1:
    xo = x

if y%2 == 1:
    yo = y

if z%2 == 1:
    zo = z

if xo > yo and xo > zo:
    print(xo)

if yo > xo and yo > zo:
    print(yo)

if zo > xo and zo > yo:
    print(zo)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how I did it..hope it helps.

```
x = 2
y =4
z=6

# Conditional program to print the smallest odd number

if x %2 == 1 or y% 2 == 1 or z% 2 == 1 : #checks if at least one is odd
    if x<y and x< z:  # checks if x is least
        print x
    elif y<z:         # x is not least,so proceeds to check if y is least
        print y
    else:
        print z       #prints z, the least number
else:
    print "None of the numbers are odd"
```

If you want the largest odd number, just reverse the signs.

Answer (score -1):

I just read the beginning of a Python text, and I'm pretty sure I found the most exhaustive method to solving this problem:

```
if x%2!=0 and y%2!=0 and z%2!=0 and x>y and x>z:
    print(x)
elif x%2!=0 and y%2!=0 and z%2!=0 and y>x and y>z:
    print(y)
elif x%2!=0 and y%2!=0 and z%2!=0 and z>x and z>y:
    print(z)
elif x%2==0 and y%2!=0 and z%2!=0 and y>z:
    print(y)
elif x%2==0 and y%2!=0 and z%2!=0 and z>y:
    print(z)
elif x%2!=0 and y%2!=0 and z%2==0 and y>x:
    print(y)
elif x%2!=0 and y%2!=0 and z%2==0 and x>y:
    print(x)
elif x%2!=0 and y%2==0 and z%2!=0 and x>z:
    print(x)
elif x%2!=0 and y%2==0 and z%2!=0 and z>x:
    print(z)
else:
    print('none of them are odd')
```

Comment: You missed a case when only one of the numbers is odd (e.g. 2, 3, 6). Currently, code will print `none of them are odd`