# debugging invalid syntax error iPython

Tags: debugging, ipython

I am greeted with the following syntax error after I execute the program thanks thkang from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732805/choose-largest-odd-number-python)

```
You entered:  ./#
Expanded to:  ./#
=================
File "./largestoddxyz.py", line 43
else: #x and z are even
   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is the code:
I am new to using Python and tried to fix the issue, but unfortunately, I wasn't able to.  Hopefully someone here can help me.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# This program exmamines variables x, y, and z 
# and prints the largest odd number among them

import sys

x,y,z = map(int,sys.argv[1:4])

if x%2 != 0:
  if y%2 != 0:
    if z%2 != 0:
      if x > y and x > z: #x is the biggest odd
        print 'x is the biggest odd ' and x
      elif y > z and y > x: #y is the biggest odd
        print 'y is the biggest odd ' and y
      elif z > x and z > y: #z is the biggest odd
        print 'z is the biggest odd ' and z

    else: #z is even
      if x > y: #x is the biggest odd
        print 'x is the biggest odd ' and x
      else: #y is the biggest odd
        print 'y is the biggest odd ' and y

  else: #y is even
      if z%2 != 0: #z is odd
        if x > z: #x is the biggest odd
          print 'x is the biggest odd ' and x
        else: #z is the biggest odd
          print 'z is the biggest odd ' and z
      else: #y,z are even and x is the biggest odd
        print 'x is the biggest odd ' and x

else: #x is even
  if y%2 != 0 and z%2 != 0: #y,z is odd
      if y > z: #y is the biggest odd
        print 'y is the biggest odd ' and y
      else: #z is the biggest odd
        print 'z is the biggest odd ' and z
  else: #x and y are even
    if z%2 != 0: #z is the biggest odd
      print 'z is the biggest odd ' and z
  else: #x and z are even
    if y%2 != 0: #y is odd
      if z%2 = 0: #z is even
        print 'y is the biggest odd ' and y

print 'finished'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indenting is wrong; note

```
  else: #x and y are even
    if z%2 != 0: #z is the biggest odd
      print 'z is the biggest odd ' and z
  else: #x and z are even
```

You want to indent the second `else` and everything below it. You may want to run [`pep8`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8) to verify that everything is in order, i.e. that you're using correct spacing and don't mix tabs and space characters.

Additionally, in the line

```
if z%2 = 0: #z is even
```

you want the comparison `==`, not the assignment `=`.

Comment: so I made the proper indentations but now I am receiving an error on line 45   ['File "largestoddxyz.py", line 45
    if z%2 = 0: #z is even
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax']

Comment: @dustin Please do **not** edit your question with the answers - that makes it harder for others to understand it, and prevents the question from serving as a signpost for everyone else who made the same mistake. Updated the answer.

Comment: that pep8 is great thanks!  I wish I knew it about it earlier.

Comment: I just added a part if all the numbers are even but it is returning another syntax error.  I ran pep8 but it is coming back with nothing.

Comment: @dustin Try to [reduce your program to a minimal one that exhibits the problem](http://sscce.org/), and just post that as a new question.