# debugging ipython after pep8 returns nothing but I still have a syntax error

Tags: debugging, syntax, ipython

After receiving the needed help from phihag on my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735512/debugging-invalid-syntax-error-ipython), I noticed that I didn't have result for all even numbers. However, I keep receiving a syntax error at line 47 invalid syntax with else.

```
else:  # x, y, and z are even
```

What could be the issue?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# This program exmamines variables x, y, and z
# and prints the largest odd number among them

import sys

x, y, z = map(int, sys.argv[1:4])

if x % 2 != 0:
    if y % 2 != 0:
        if z % 2 != 0:
            if x > y and x > z:  # x is the biggest odd
                print 'x is the biggest odd ', x
            elif y > z and y > x:  # y is the biggest odd
                print 'y is the biggest odd ', y
            elif z > x and z > y:  # z is the biggest odd
                print 'z is the biggest odd ', z

        else:  # z is even
            if x > y:  # x is the biggest odd
                print 'x is the biggest odd ', x
            else:  # y is the biggest odd
                print 'y is the biggest odd ', y

    else:  # y is even
        if z % 2 != 0:  # z is odd
            if x > z:  # x is the biggest odd
                print 'x is the biggest odd ', x
            else:  # z is the biggest odd
                print 'z is the biggest odd ', z
        else:  # y,z are even and x is the biggest odd
            print 'x is the biggest odd ', x

else:  # x is even
    if y % 2 != 0 and z % 2 != 0:  # y,z is odd
        if y > z:  # y is the biggest odd
            print 'y is the biggest odd ', y
        else:  # z is the biggest odd
            print 'z is the biggest odd ', z
    else:  # x and y are even
        if z % 2 != 0:  # z is the biggest odd
            print 'z is the biggest odd ', z
        else:  # x and z are even
            if y % 2 != 0:  # y is odd
                if z % 2 == 0:  # z is even
                    print 'y is the biggest odd ', y
    else:  # x, y, and z are even
        if z % 2 == 0:
            print 'x, y, and z are even.'

print 'finished'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two `else`s at the same indentation level, one after the other, which is not valid. Did you mean for one of them to be an `elif`?

Comment: ok I didn't know.  I will try the elif and see how it goes.  I made the change but I have the same error

Comment: I changed the 2nd else to elif

Comment: Just elif? elif requires another expression after it.

Comment: what else would it require?