# Initializing integer variables for comparisons

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working my way through the MIT Open Courseware class [Introduction to Computer Science and Programming in Python](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-0001-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-in-python-fall-2016/) and I've spent an embarrassing amount of time trying to wrap my head around the "Finger Exercise" from the textbook:

> Write a program that examines three variables—x, y, and z—and
>   prints the largest odd number among them. If none of them are odd, it should
>   print a message to that effect.

I wrote a couple of solutions that didn't quite work, missing odd numbers if there were larger even numbers.  I finally threw in the towel and searched here for solutions that others people working on this class had asked.  [This solution from AFDev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19595603/4642253) seemed to be the simplest to me (in the context of what the intent of the exercise was and how concise the solution was.)  I combined that with my user input to get the following:

```
x=int(input('Enter your first number:'))
y=int(input('Enter your second number:'))
z=int(input('Enter your third number:'))
largest = None
if x%2:
    largest = x
if y%2:
    if y > largest:
        largest = y
if z%2:
    if z > largest:
        largest = z
if largest:
    print ('The largest odd number is', largest)
else:
    print ('There are no odd numbers.')
```

This works great, as long as x is an odd number. If x is zero or an even number, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

The little bit of Googling I did said that Python 2 was a little more liberal in allowing comparisons between `NoneType` and integers.  I changed the line to initialize `largest = 0`, but then realized that this would give invalid results if the user input a negative number.

I tweaked the code to the following:

```
x=int(input('Enter your first number:'))
y=int(input('Enter your second number:'))
z=int(input('Enter your third number:'))

largest = None
if x%2:
    largest = x
if y%2:
    if largest == None:
        largest = y
    if y > largest:
        largest = y
if z%2:
    if largest == None:
        largest = z
    if z > largest:
        largest = z
if largest:
    print ('The largest odd number is', largest)
else:
    print ('There are no odd numbers.')
```

Is there a better way to initialize (for lack of a better term) "largest" so that I can compare it to an integer or is the way I'm doing it good enough?

I understand that there are better ways to compare the numbers to find the largest (I found `max` when googling). I'm trying to baby-step my way through this stuff.

Comment: Initialize `largest` to a very very large negative number, for example `largest = -1e10`.

Comment: One workaround to avoid `TypeError` in your first code is to assign a very large negative number to `largest` (like `largest = -999999`).

Comment: By the way, zero *is* an even number!

Comment: Initialize largest to `float('-inf')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`None` seems fine if you're going to do it this way. (I'd say it's safer than using a large negative number.) You can get round the code duplication with `None` as e.g.

```
if largest is None or y > largest:
    largest = y
```

Couple of things, compare to `None` with `is`. Second, if the first part of an `or` is True, the second part won't be executed (called short-circuiting), so you won't get an error trying to compare a `None` using `>`.

Answer (score 3):

Or don't initialize it at all - just keep a Boolean to keep track of whether an odd number has been found yet.

```
still_looking = True
if x % 2:
    largest, still_looking = x, False
if y % 2 and (still_looking or y > largest):
    largest, still_looking = y, False
if z % 2 and (still_looking or z > largest):
    largest, still_looking = z, False

if still_looking:
    print('There are no odd numbers.')
else:
    print('The largest odd number is', largest)
```

The repetitious code at the start then screams to be replaced with a uniform loop:

```
still_looking = True
for val in x, y, z:
    if val % 2 and (still_looking or val > largest):
        largest, still_looking = val, False
```

Comment: You might want to explain a *little* about tuple unpacking there if we are talking baby steps! Otherwise, +1

Comment: I'm saving the second half of you comment and revisiting it in a couple of weeks, haha.

Answer (score 2):

I guess using a very large negative number, to make sure you're good.
doing something like :

```
largest = -float('inf')
```

and by the end checking this :

```
if largest == -float('inf'):
  print("There are no odd numbers")
else:
  print(largest)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do:

```
x=int(input('Enter your first number:'))
y=int(input('Enter your second number:'))
z=int(input('Enter your third number:'))

li=[e for e in (x,y,z) if e % 2]   # find all odd numbers from x,y,z

print('{} is largest odd number'.format(max(li)) if li else 'all input even')
```

This works because an empty container in Python is `False` and the list `li` will be empty if there are no odd numbers. You can use `max` to find the largest odd number if there are any and the Python ternary of `[if true clause] if [boolean test] else [what do do otherwise]`

You can do the same thing this way:

```
li=[e for e in (x,y,z) if e % 2]
if li:
    print ('The largest odd number is', max(li))
else:
    print ('There are no odd numbers.')
```

---

If you don't want to use the [max function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max), you can write your own:

```
def mymax(li):
    max_=None 
    if li:
        max_=li[0]
    for e in li:
        if e>max_: max_=e
    return max_
```

Comment: That's a fine approach, but read through the end of the OP's post - "I understand that there are better ways to compare the numbers to find the largest (I found max when googling.) I'm trying to baby-step my way through this stuff."

Comment: I guess baby steps are in the eye of the beholder! I find ideomatic Python usually is fairly clear even to those who are learning it vs purely procedural Python (this, new line this, new line, if x: new line, etc) gets really wordy and confusing. At least to this baby...

Comment: I've grabbed your solution and will take a look at it in a couple of weeks.  I really appreciate everyone's help!

Answer (score -1):

Instead of putting:

```
largest = None
```

you should put:

```
largest = -1 * sys.maxsize + 1
```

Comment: There is no `sys.maxint` on Python 3.

Comment: This won't work in Python3, and even if it did, it's ugly and a poor idea. It leads to a hidden dependency on an implementation detail.

Comment: ``sys.maxsize`` is the maximum of a *machine* integer (e.g. as used by ``len``). It is not the maximum of the ``int`` type.