# Python: Choosing a large number as initial max

Tags: python, python-3.x

I come from a Java background, where to find the maximum value in a list, you could do something like:

```
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for (int value : list)
    max = Math.max(max, value);
```

Ignoring that there are better ways to solve this specific problem, what is the equivalent of doing `Integer.MIN_VALUE` in Python? Or, is there never a reason to need an arbitrary really small number?

Comment: `float('-inf')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Initializing Integer Variables for Comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51697030/12299000)

Comment: `max_val = max(list)` ? putting aside the fact that you should not use `list` as a variable name

Comment: It would indeed make some algo cleaner, but since Python 3, integers are only bounded by the available memory... Long story short, either in your use case, you know that all the values of the list are bounded (for example they are result of a measure, or are extracted from a database) and you can use that bound, or you have to initialize to None as shown in the accepted answer to the duplicate, or use `Math.inf`.

Comment: Defaulting to `MIN_VALUE` looks awkward. What if the list is empty? In python, the idiomatic solution is `result = max(lst)`, which will raise an exception if `lst` is empty. That's much more pythonic than having special-case handling for a `MIN_VALUE` result (assuming that is not a valid value in `lst`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, you can do something like that

```
from math import inf
'initialize maximum with very small value'
maximum=float('-inf')
'traverse the array'
for v in array:
    maximum=max(maximum,v)
print(maximum)
```

Or You can use `max()` function directly on the given array

```
print(max(array))
```

Answer (score 0):

Python implements int as unbounded bigints. So there is no equivalent to MIN_INTEGER and MAX_INTEGER.